# how to fetch category from firebase and use as flutter dropdown?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

can anyone find the error in this I cannot fetch the category from firebase to flutter dropdown?

this is my code

```
Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Select Category', style: boldTextStyle(size: 18)),
                8.height,
                Container(
                  width: context.width() * 0.45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: radius(), color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    underline: Offstage(),
                    items: categories.map((e) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(e.name.validate()), value: e);
                    }).toList(),
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: selectedCategory,
                    onChanged: (dynamic c) {
                      selectedCategory = c;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

I cannot display the data from firebase to dropdown after getting the data

Comment: Can you write what data or error do you get from Firebase?

Comment: are you facing issue with retrieve data from firebase? or after getting data unable to set in dropdown ? please specified whats your concern!!!

Comment: I cannot display the data from firebase to dropdown after getting the data

Comment: Why not? What is keeping you from doing that? Can you edit your question to show what you've already tried to read the data from Firebase and show it in your dropdown?